# Are there any MGF1 and OS2IP functions available in C?

Tags: rsa, implementation

I need  MGF1 and OS2IP functions, as defined in the [PKCS #1 v2.1: RSA Cryptography Standard](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2125).

Is there anything available in [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/), or any other open C library?

Answer (score 4):

You can find MGF1 in [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/source/). Source file "crypto/rsa/rsa_oaep.c" has a function called "PKCS1_MGF1" that implements MGF1. The function signature is:

```
int PKCS1_MGF1(unsigned char *mask, long len, const unsigned char *seed, long seedlen, const EVP_MD *dgst)
```

See the wrapper function "MGF1" defined right below it for a more general case of using it.

As for OS2IP, I don't see an explicit method for converting to/from it in OpenSSL, presumably because the integers start and end in that format, so they never convert them.

OS2IP and I2OSP are a pair of straight-forward methods of encoding and decoding a large number to an octet string. The idea for OS2IP is that you simply represent the integer in [big endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) byte order. How you would use OS2IP to encode an integer depends entirely on how the integer is original represented before conversion.

The bottom line for OS2IP/I2OSP is that it's more a function of your original integer than a function of RSA. Find a way to convert the original integer to/from a big endian byte string, either by using a "toBigEndian" / "fromBigEndian" type function for your original integer or by making one manually. I don't think you'll find a generic method anywhere.

To do it manually: If you understand how the original integer format works, you can manually convert bytes to/from the original format and the octet string. If you can do multiplication, division, addition, and subtraction on the original integer, you can just calculate the octet stream manually with a few lines of code and a loop using the [OS2IP description](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#page-9).